# How to make sure no extra fields are returned in the response

Tags: karate

My actual api response is

```
{
"data": {
"0000164": {
"2019-02-11": {
"MAPLE": 5,
"OAK": 15
}
}
},
"request_data": null,
"status": 200
}
```

This is my expected api response

```
{
"data": {
"0000164": {
"2019-02-11": {
"MAPLE": 5,
"OAK": 15
}
}
},
"status": 200
}
```

If you notice I don't want my api response to have **"request_data"** field or any other field extra other than the expected

How do I make sure that my api is not returning any junk key value pairs

Currently this is how I am validating

```
And match $.data.0000164.2019-02-11.MAPLE == 5
And match $.data.0000164.2019-02-11.OAK == 15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specifically check that `request_data` is not present:

```
* match response.request_data == '#notpresent'
```

I don't understand your second question, isn't this what Karate does by default:

```
* match response ==
"""
{
  data: '#object',
  status: '#number'
}
"""
```

Read the section on fuzzy matching carefully: https://github.com/intuit/karate#fuzzy-matching

Comment: What if developer introduces some key in response ? 
In your answer , I know the key name . But what if I don't know the key name ?

Comment: @SourabhChapali try the second part of my answer and see. if any other key is present it will fail. isn't that what you want !?

Comment: Yes , Thanks I will try the same

Answer (score 1):

If you know all the expected keys from the response, you could write expected **schema** for that and `match` it as `==` to stricly validate the expected keys as well.

eg for the above scenario,

```
{
  "data": {
    "0000164": {
      "2019-02-11": {
        "MAPLE": "#number",
        "OAK": "#number"
      }
    }
  },
  "status": 200
}
```

There are many other ways like retrieving all the keys from the JSON and look for unexpected keys.