# The notpresent keyword is not working in Karate

Tags: karate

I am trying to assert that a key is not in the JSON response. This is the response

```
   {
    "_type": "UserAccount",
    "accountName": "Account_Name",
    "accountType": "regular",
    "whiteList": true,
    "sfAccountId": "1",
    "preferredLanguage": "english",
    "imageSize": "highRes",
    "_id": "775a8451-6a07-42da-a199-fe98f44bdc06"
}
```

I have tried both of these steps according to the documentation [karate#null-and-notpresent](https://github.com/intuit/karate#null-and-notpresent) and this answer from [Peter Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53723891/how-to-make-sure-no-extra-fields-are-returned-in-the-response/53724478#53724478)

```
And match response.appClientId == '#notpresent'
And match response == {appClientId:'#notpresent'}
```

However this is the error I keep getting for the first step above

```
com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: No results for path: $['appClientId']
```

and for the second step

```
com.intuit.karate.KarateException: path: $, actual
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your version is out of date, the below works for me in 0.9.1:

```
* def response =
"""
{
    "_type": "UserAccount",
    "accountName": "Account_Name",
    "accountType": "regular",
    "whiteList": true,
    "sfAccountId": "1",
    "preferredLanguage": "english",
    "imageSize": "highRes",
    "_id": "775a8451-6a07-42da-a199-fe98f44bdc06"
}
"""
* match response.appClientId == '#notpresent'
* match response contains { appClientId: '#notpresent' }
```

Comment: We are currently using v0.8.0 is this feature not supported in that version?

Comment: @Ilan_p I think some of the bug fixes in 0.9.0 are related to this

Comment: The following step 
`* match response contains { appClientId: '#notpresent' }` works for my needs and also doesn't require update to v 0.9.1